# apt-get update and DNS issues inside of Docker on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, apt, dns, docker

I'm running Ubuntu. If I run `apt-get update` inside the Docker container I get `Temporary failure resolving 'gta-update.does-it.net'` which is normal since `/etc/resolv.conf` contains this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

But how should I change the DNS settings if there are no editors available inside Docker (like nano, etc...) ?

I tried with this on host side but it didn't help:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"
```

the `/etc/resolv.conf` inside Docker is still the same (even after docker service restart)

Answer (score 0):

At the end I had to modify default route to use different network and than I was able to go to Internet and use apt-get to install nano...